# IBM Bluemix iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix push notifications but get errors when trying to register my device.

```
2015-08-03 14:14:57.106 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [INFO] [IMFPushClient] -[IMFPushClient registerDeviceToken:completionHandler:] in IMFPushClient.m:70 :: Verifying previous device registration.
2015-08-03 14:14:57.239 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [WARN] [IMF] -[IMFAuthorizationManager cachedAuthorizationHeader] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:447 :: There is no cached authorization header, use obtainAuthorizationHeaderWithCompletionHandler to get the header
2015-08-03 14:14:59.051 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [ERROR] [IMF_REQUEST] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest requestFailed:error:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:368 :: Status code='403' error='Expected status code in (200-299), got 403' response='/*-secure-
{"reason":"Cannot find application 'org.kp.consumer.myhealth'"}*/'
2015-08-03 14:14:59.056 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [ERROR] [IMF] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest requestFailed:error:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:372 :: Error=Error Domain=WLAFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 403" UserInfo=0x1467a850 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=/*-secure-
{"reason":"Cannot find application 'org.kp.consumer.myhealth'"}*/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x14692990> { URL: https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance }, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14574580> { URL: https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 03 Aug 2015 21:14:58 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "98e47b88-88c4-41eb-58c6-e64285a1369e";
    "X-Client-IP" = "70.197.4.111";
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 3589775105;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 403}
2015-08-03 14:14:59.121 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [FATAL] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager onFailureWithResponse:error:] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: {"reason":"Cannot find application 'org.kp.consumer.myhealth'"}
2015-08-03 14:14:59.127 BluemixNotifications[443:251675] [ERROR] [IMFPushClient] __55-[IMFPushClient registerDeviceToken:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in IMFPushClient.m:139 :: Error while verifying previous registration - Error is: Error Domain=WLAFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Failed to register client: Expected status code in (200-299), got 403" UserInfo=0x1458d160 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=/*-secure-
{"reason":"Cannot find application 'org.kp.consumer.myhealth'"}*/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x14692990> { URL: https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance }, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14574580> { URL: https://testpushnotifications.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/clients/instance } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 03 Aug 2015 21:14:58 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "98e47b88-88c4-41eb-58c6-e64285a1369e";
    "X-Client-IP" = "70.197.4.111";
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 3589775105;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to register client: Expected status code in (200-299), got 403}
```

I am thinking {"reason":"Cannot find application 'org.kp.consumer.myhealth'"} means that my provisioning profile needs to match my app name within IBM Bluemix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your Application ID is not matching what Bluemix has. Please reference this [documentation](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/ios#push) about setting up your iOS app with the Bluemix SDK to ensure your application is recognized and authorized by Bluemix. Make sure to also check the other sections such as 'Getting Started with Push' to ensure you are setup to authorize and communicate with Bluemix's push service.

This could not be the case but you did not post your application configuration file or push notification code, so this is a best guess. Feel free to update your question with this code so a more specific answer can be given.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I will post my findings tomorrow.

Comment: After going through that documentation and others for just setup (need to reorganize the docs) I am still getting the same error. From your answer, "It appears your Application ID is not matching what Bluemix has" how do I set Bluemix identifier on their end? I could not find it in dashboard and its not in their docs.

Comment: I created a new app and there was the field to set the bundle identifier for the app. Now it is working and I am not getting that error. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! Happy hacking